# FOSuserBundle override controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

What is the right way to pass more variables to [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) settings twig template (`Profile/show_content.html.twig`) in Symfony 3.4?

I basically want to rewrite [`showAction()` method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ProfileController.php#L49) and pass more than `user` variable ti twig template.

I tried to following this [tutorial](https://github.com/gimler/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md). It seems it does no longer work with Symfony 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it (and there might be better methods) is simply create a new controller with a route to the original 'show route', together with the variables I want to pass. Here is an example of the `showAction()` with an extra variable `rendered_address`:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Show the user.
    * @Route("/profile/show")
    */
    public function showAction()
    {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $address = $this->getUser()->renderAddress(); // here is get my variable

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/show.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'rendered_address' => $address // here is pass my variable
    ));
    }
}
```